# adding hashicorp/precise32 fails to complete install on xp

Tags: windows-xp, vagrant

I am new to vagrant and am trying to install hashicorp/precise32 on windows xp but it fails at the very end with a message "The box failed to unpackage ...." I have googled this problem but no definite answers on how to complete this task any help would be most appreciated

Comment: I am using vagrant version 1.6.5

Comment: I think you have make a dynamic link to vagrant_home because ruby does not like spaces

Comment: one problem I have found is that when you type vagrant up it times out on connection haven't got to the bottom of this yet still searching for an answer to this one but there must be a work around will post when I find or figure this one out

Comment: I should have pointed out above that precise32 works fine but I was trying out laravel/homestead and I have found a workaround for that installation, simply googled homestead 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on Github and it works hope this helps you out Artful_dodger its a solution by BakerCo he says "my solution was to download the basic_bsdtar.exe from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/bsdtar/ and rename it to bsdtar.exe and place it in C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gnuwin32\bin\"

Comment: I tried this out this morning and it works thank you user2033464